# How to pass java variable to java script function

Tags: java, javascript, cordova

I need to pass a Java variable to a JavaScript function and I need to store that Java variable in JavaScript. What should I do?

Consider this Java code:

```
NodeList list = rootElement_plutus.getElementsByTagName("StatusMessage");
if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) 
{
    NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();
    if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) 
    {
         STATUS_Plutus = subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
         System.out.println("output:  "+STATUS_Plutus);
     "Here i need to pass variable  'STATUS_Plutus' to javascript function"  
     }
}
```

I am not using any servlets here. its just a normal fn.

Can u please give exact line so that I can paste it over there...

Javascript function is on the another page...

Comment: how are you running java on webpage

Comment: The question carries no relevant information. Please refer some Servlet / JSP tutorial firts.

Comment: It will run on mobile browser

Comment: Applets and servlets not been used any where..!!!!

Comment: *"can u pls give exact line"*  Can you please spell words like 'you' and 'please' correctly, and add an upper case letter to the start of sentences to make them easier to read?

Comment: @user1323195: *"Applets and servlets not been used any where..!!!!"* See Ankit's question in the first comment: **How is the Java being run**? Where? In what environment? Why do you think JavaScript is also available in that environment? The question as it stands cannot be answered.

Comment: I don't think that without Servlet or Applet Java program could respond to mobile browser. Please explain the platform of your application.

Comment: @Amber I am using Phonegap application which connects to mobile browser. It runs on Android tablet.

Comment: Are you trying to make any android application using phonegap? It sounds more like that.Then retag it, And change the question heading. Otherwise You will get more and more negetive votes. For your info you cant simply pass a java variable to javascript. And also no need to put same question twice.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13658291/how-to-pass-core-java-variables-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: @Ankit Gautam Its pure android code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but you could try something like this (since you are alluding to passing DIRECTLY from Java to Javascript) ... (only applies to **JDK1.6+**) ...

```
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
String javascript = "3+2*(4+5)";
System.out.println(engine.eval(javascript));
```

p.s. Make sure you have previously imported these..

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
```